# Building Cairo for Windows with MinGW (Problems linking libpng)

Tags: build, makefile, mingw, cairo, libpng

I'm trying to build [cairo](http://www.cairographics.org/) on Windows using MinGW (and MSYS). I am following the instrucions on [Compiling GTK+ 2.16.4 for Windows](http://kemovitra.blogspot.com/2009/06/compiling-gtk-2-for-windows.html), except that I'm using the latest versions whenever possible, i.e:

- zlib-1.2.3
- libpng-1.2.42
- pixman-0.17.4
- cairo-1.8.8

This works pretty well up until when I try to build the actual cairo. The configuration succeeds, but during make cairo seems to have problems linking to my build of libpng. After a little while I get a long list of errors such as this:

> ```
> .libs/cairo-png.o: In function `png_simple_error_callback':
> /home/user/cairo-1.8.8/src/cairo-png.c:95: undefined reference to `png_get_error_ptr'
> .libs/cairo-png.o: In function `png_simple_warning_callback':
> /home/user/cairo-1.8.8/src/cairo-png.c:112: undefined reference to `png_get_error_ptr'
>
> ...
>
> .libs/cairo-png.o: In function `stream_read_func':
> /home/user/cairo-1.8.8/src/cairo-png.c:686: undefined reference to `png_error'
> collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
> make[3]: *** [libcairo.la] Error 1
> make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/user/cairo-1.8.8/src'
> make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
> make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/user/cairo-1.8.8/src'
> make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
> make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/user/cairo-1.8.8'
> make: *** [all] Error 2
> ```

I have tried using an older version of libpng (1.2.40, the version being distributed by [The GTK+ Project](http://www.gtk.org/download-windows.html)), with the same result. When I run "pkg-config -cflags -libs libpng" I get "-IC:/MinGW/include/libpng12  -LC:/MinGW/lib -lpng12", which seems correct. I'm sure I'm making some stupid mistake, but I cannot tell what it is.

Comment: Well, it turns out that my build of libpng was broken. When I compared it to a build that I had done a while ago on a different machine I noticed that 'libpng12.dll.a' was much too small (<1kb). I couldn't figure out a way to make it work so I just copied the version from the other machine and it fixed my problems with cairo. This I not very satisfying, but since I already spent more time on this than I should have, I'll just move on right now. If anybody runs into the same problem, they can use the same approach and get a working version from GnuWin (http://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuwin32).

Comment: Quick follow-up: The same thing happened with another library (libcroco), so I think something is wrong with my MinGW/MSYS. The builds complete without error message, but the *.dll.a files end up smaller than they should be and whenever another program tries to use those libraries it fails during linking. I don't know what is wrong, I've used MinGW before and never had that problem. It could have something to do with me using Windows 7 (as opposed to Windows XP, which I used previously), but I haven't found anything online saying this could lead to problems...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently this is a known issue. I don't know how managed to miss it, given that it is even mentioned in the [blog](http://kemovitra.blogspot.com/2008/01/installing-mingw-on-windows.html) that I was following (I think it's safe to assume that this also applies to Windows 7, given that I tried the third suggestion and it fixed my problem):

> Now, let's install MinGW. Note that MinGW doesn't run smoothly on Windows Vista because of weird filesystem restrictions. The workaround is
>
> - to install MinGW on FAT filesystem,
> - to work in the safe mode, or
> - to use MinGW Portable which is said to be working well.

Comment: Just when I thought I had made sense out of it all: While using MinGW Portable fixed my problem with libpng, the problem with libcroco still persists...

Answer (score 2):

> I noticed that 'libpng12.dll.a' was much too small (<1kb).

It is so due to incorrect symbols in libpng.vers (symbols have extra `_` at beginning). After libpng build I removed extra `_` and recreated libpng12.dll.a manually - size is OK now.
But... The correct import library doesn't resolve your (and my) problem.

Comment: I filed a bug report on this, and included my little fix: https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&atid=105624&aid=3590511&group_id=5624