# Compiling libpng and using it with netbeans and mingw

Tags: c++, netbeans, mingw, libpng

I have only previously used visual studio for developing c++ but I've just moved to netbeans and am having some issues.

I got mingw installed so that my projects will compile but I dont know how to add external libraries to that. I want to use a static library, not a dll.

The library I specifically am looking at is [libpng](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html)

I hope this isn't too IDE specific, I'm also looking to know how to prepare the library.

Windows OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out more or less. I used the [cmake gui](http://www.cmake.org/), configured for msys `make` and mingw `g++` and `gcc`, on the zlib source directory and then ran msys `make` and `make install` on the output directory. After that I did the same on libpng, but I had to add some variables to point to the zlib include and library directories within cmake.

Then in netbeans, I right clicked>>properties on my project and added include and lib location for each of the two libraries. I also could have copied the files into my mingw directories.

Now I'm just stuck with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2151145/building-cairo-for-windows-with-mingw-problems-linking-libpng) issue.